# Repeating a jquery animation

Tags: jquery, animation, repeat

How can I get this animation sequence to repeat after a delay of 5 seconds?

```
function homeanimation(){  

$('#identity-text-01').fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);  
$('#identity-image-01').delay(2000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);

$('#print-text-01').delay(6000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
$('#print-image-01').delay(7000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);

$('#web-text-01').delay(12000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
$('#web-image-01').delay(13000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);

$('#wayfinding-text-01').delay(18000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
$('#wayfinding-image-01').delay(19000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);

$('#exhibit-text-01').delay(24000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
$('#exhibit-image-01').delay(25000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);

$('#recognition-text-01').delay(30000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
$('#recognition-image-01').delay(31000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);

$('#packaging-text-01').delay(36000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
$('#packaging-image-01').delay(37000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000);
};
homeanimation();
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd use `setInterval` with timeout of `5000`.

Comment: @pimvdb Make that an answer! (And give an example...)

Answer (score 1):

Change the last line:

```
$('#packaging-image-01').delay(37000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000);
```

to:

```
$('#packaging-image-01').delay(37000).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000);
setTimeout('homeanimation()', 5000);
```

Comment: this will repeat the whole animation after 5 seconds, but it won't have completed yet since the last component of the animation doesn't start for 37 seconds so you'll be overlapping. you need to either put the 'setTimeout' in a callback from the last animation step, or on a much longer delay

Comment: It's not exactly good practice to use a string as the argument to `setTimeout`. Use the function itself instead:  `setTimeout(homeanimation, 5000)`.

Comment: @lonesomeday unfortunately IE can be wonky about that method too, I usually find it best to pass in an anonymous function object: `setTimeout(function() { homeanimation(); }, 5000)`

Comment: @lonesomeday: W3schools quotes the function name (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp). Can you provide a reference that says this is a bad practice?

Comment: @George Cummins [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/) Should get you started on your intervention.

Comment: Wow. W3fools is one of the least accurate, most shrill sites I have encountered in a long time. But to avoid a religious discussion, please provide an authoritative source for your claim "It's not exactly good practice to use a string as the argument to setTimeout."

Comment: @George Cummins I found that `setTimeout(function() { homeanimation(); }, 43000);` works and does what I want it to do. Thanks! But I have a question that is related to this animation regarding pulling in images with php. Should I start a new question or ask here?

Comment: I found that `setTimeout(function() { homeanimation(); }, 43000);` works and does what I want it to do. Thanks! But I have a question that is related to this animation regarding pulling in images with php. Should I start a new question or ask here?

Comment: If you start a new question, it will be available to a wider audience, and you will have the benefit of the formatting options available in the post that are unavailable in the comments.

Comment: @George Cummins - 'Javascript the good parts - Page 111' http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Good-Parts-Douglas-Crockford/dp/0596517742 - in short, setTimeout uses 'eval' to evalulate the function by invoking the compiler which has performance and security implications and it 'frustrates' jslint

Answer (score 1):

You can delay the execution of any code in javascript by setting a timeout:

```
function MyAlert(msg) {
   alert(msg);
}

//By using a function object as the first parameter
//any variables you need to use/pass will still be in scope
var msg = "Hey there!";
var delay = 5000; //the delay in milliseconds to wait (in this case 5 seconds)
setTimeout(function() { MyAlert(msg); }, delay);
```